# EIN on Aquamacs 3.0 not working

Tags: emacs, jupyter-notebook, aquamacs

#### After starting my iPython Notebook server in Terminal, I try:

```
M-x ein:notebooklist-open RET
```

#### this gives following error:

```
defvar: Symbol's value as variable is void: c-mode-syntax-table
```

(source: [ein documentation](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-ipython-notebook/) )

I'm at a loss how to debug/fix this.

---

I just got the newly released Aquamacs 3.0, and installed the required packages (websocket, request, auto-complete) before installing the ein package.

Preferences.el include (probably redundant with Aquamacs 3.0):

```
(require 'cl)
(require 'websocket)
(require 'request)
(require 'ein)
```

I am on Mavericks, have been using emacs for ~2 yrs.

### EDIT

for completeness sake, at request of lunaryorn:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable c-mode-syntax-table)
  byte-code("\302!\303\304\305  #\210\303\306\305   #\210   )\207" [c-mode-syntax-table table make-syntax-table modify-syntax-entry 46 "w" 95] 4)
  (defvar ein:dotty-syntax-table (byte-code "\302!\303\304\305  #\210\303\306\305   #\210   )\207" [c-mode-syntax-table table make-syntax-table modify-syntax-entry 46 "w" 95] 4) ("/Users/pavo/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/elpa/ein-20130711.104/ein-utils.elc" . 2990))
  require(ein-utils)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-545884> nil "/Users/pavo/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/elpa/ein-20130711.104/ein-core.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1143
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/pavo/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/elpa/ein-20130711.104/ein-core.el" "/Users/pavo/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/elpa/ein-20130711.104/ein-core.el" nil t)
  require(ein-core)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/pavo/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/elpa/ein-20130711.104/ein-notebooklist.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 952
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/pavo/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/elpa/ein-20130711.104/ein-notebooklist.el" "/Users/pavo/Library/Application Support/Aquamacs Emacs/elpa/ein-20130711.104/ein-notebooklist.el" nil t)
  autoload-do-load((autoload "ein-notebooklist" "Open notebook list buffer.\n\n(fn &optional URL-OR-PORT NO-POPUP)" t nil) ein:notebooklist-open)
  command-execute(ein:notebooklist-open record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "ein:notebooklist-open")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

Comment: First of all, `M-x toggle-debug-on-error`, then try again, and post the complete backtrace.

Comment: +1 for that command, wasn't aware of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess, `c-mode-syntax-table` is defined in `cc-mode.el`, it seems `ein` uses this somewhere in its code, can you do `M-: (require 'cc-mode) RET` and try again.

Comment: that was it. above I had (require 'cl) at the suggestion of a friend  who provided the same reasoning. But cc-mode is what was required

Comment: If possible, report this to the developers of this package.  It's a bug in the code, and should be fixed on their side.

Comment: Agree with lunaryon, this should be reported as bug.